# Media queries of iphone 4s is taken for Iphone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, html, css, responsive-design

I have this simple css block:

```
    @media only screen
    and (min-device-width: 375px)
    and (max-device-width: 667px)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {  // iphone 6
      color: red;
    }
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width: 320px) 
    and (max-device-width: 480px) 
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {  //iphone 4S
      color: blue;
    }
```

**When running on iphone 6**, color is...blue.
(There are no other places where I define color property).

Why?

Comment: Seems to be a problem of order. Reversing the order of the nested media blocks does the job.

Comment: But I don't figure out why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width the iPhone 6 reports to browsers in portrait orientation is 375px. That means, your first color rule is overridden by the second color rule since the browser's reported resolution passes that media query. (It is between 320px and 480px.)

Since your media queries overlap, the last one will be used for browsers that pass both media queries.

Comment: I was expected that the iphone 6 has a width size superior to 480 ... Thus I find those media queries not fitting well the specific iphone sizes since there are not really exclusive: they could overlap each other...